# Ending xml tag in treeview control

Tags: wpf, xml, treeview

I'm currently working on a simple xml viewer control to display some xml files with easy navigation possibilities, like when you open a xml file in the internet explorer.

For this I found a nice control in the msdn forums:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.CustomControl.Viewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:xmlstack="clr-namespace:System.Xml;assembly=System.Xml">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmlValueBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmAttributeBrush" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmlTagBrush" Color="DarkMagenta" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="xmlMarkBrush" Color="Blue" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="attributeTemplate">
            <StackPanel Margin="3,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource xmAttributeBrush}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" Text="=&quot;" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource xmlValueBrush}" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" Text="&quot;" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
        </Style>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="treeViewTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=child::node()}">
            <StackPanel Margin="3,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock x:Name="startTag"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}"
                           Text="&lt;" />

                <TextBlock x:Name="xmlTag"
                           Margin="0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmlTagBrush}"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />

                <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes}"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource attributeTemplate}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>

                <TextBlock x:Name="endTag"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}"
                           Text="&gt;" />
            </StackPanel>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeType}">
                    <DataTrigger.Value>
                        <xmlstack:XmlNodeType>Text</xmlstack:XmlNodeType>
                    </DataTrigger.Value>
                    <Setter TargetName="xmlTag" Property="Text" Value="{Binding InnerText}" />
                    <Setter TargetName="xmlTag" Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter TargetName="startTag" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter TargetName="endTag" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasChildNodes}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="endTag" Property="Text" Value=" /&gt;" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="xmlTree"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treeViewTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code-Behind:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Xml;

namespace WpfApplication1.CustomControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Viewer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Viewer : UserControl
    {
        private XmlDocument _xmldocument;

        public Viewer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public XmlDocument xmlDocument
        {
            get { return _xmldocument; }
            set
            {
                _xmldocument = value;
                BindXMLDocument();
            }
        }

        private void BindXMLDocument()
        {
            if (_xmldocument == null)
            {
                xmlTree.ItemsSource = null;
                return;
            }

            XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();
            provider.Document = _xmldocument;
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = provider;
            binding.XPath = "child::node()";
            xmlTree.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem now is that I want to display the ending tag of child nodes, in the following example marked with stars:

```
<root>
    <node>Test*</node>*
*</root>*
```

I don't know how to realize this, are there good suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: look at how they did the opening tags (e.g. `<node>`) and go from there..

Comment: yes, i know how to build the ending node but I don't get it where to add the textblocks so the ending tag is displayed after the sub nodes. :|

Comment: what happens if you put it under the last TextBlock in the HierDT?

Comment: then the ending tag is directly added after the opening tag, but not under the subnodes. It looks like this: <root></root><node></node>Test

Comment: i don't think it's going to work with `TreeView` and HierDTs..

Comment: do you think it's possible with other controls? i have searched some days for it but found nothing useful.

Comment: maybe try a ListBox with a custom template and an indent converter (internet search `wpf indent tree datagrid`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the `WebBrowser` control.

I found no good solution with `TreeView`, but I'm full satisfied with this code, because it's full MVVM:

Create a dependency property for WebBrowser controls called `BindableXmlData`:

```
Public Class AttachedWebBrowserProperties

#Region "BindableXmlDataProperty"

    Public Shared ReadOnly BindableXmlDataProperty As DependencyProperty = _
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableXmlData", _
                                        GetType(String), _
                                        GetType(AttachedWebBrowserProperties), _
                                        New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf BindableXmlDataPropertyChanged))

    Public Shared Function GetBindableXmlData(ByVal obj As DependencyObject) As ICommand
        Return CType(obj.GetValue(BindableXmlDataProperty), ICommand)
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetBindableXmlData(ByVal obj As DependencyObject, ByVal value As String)
        obj.SetValue(BindableXmlDataProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub BindableXmlDataPropertyChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim browser As WebBrowser = TryCast(d, WebBrowser)

        If browser IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim xmldata As String = TryCast(e.NewValue, String)

            If xmldata IsNot Nothing Then
                browser.NavigateToString(xmldata)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Then add a new file to your solution called `XmlToHtmlStylesheet.xslt` as embedded resource with following content:

```
<!--
 |
 | XSLT REC Compliant Version of IE5 Default Stylesheet
 |
 | Original version by Jonathan Marsh (jmarsh@xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
 | http://msdn.microsoft.com/xml/samples/defaultss/defaultss.xsl
 |
 | Conversion to XSLT 1.0 REC Syntax by Steve Muench (smuench@xxxxxxxxxx)
 |
 +-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="no" method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT>
          <xsl:comment>
            <![CDATA[
                  function f(e){
                     if (e.className=="ci") {
                       if (e.children(0).innerText.indexOf("\n")>0) fix(e,"cb");
                     }
                     if (e.className=="di") {
                       if (e.children(0).innerText.indexOf("\n")>0) fix(e,"db");
                     } e.id="";
                  }
                  function fix(e,cl){
                    e.className=cl;
                    e.style.display="block";
                    j=e.parentElement.children(0);
                    j.className="c";
                    k=j.children(0);
                    k.style.visibility="visible";
                    k.href="#";
                  }
                  function ch(e) {
                    mark=e.children(0).children(0);
                    if (mark.innerText=="+") {
                      mark.innerText="-";
                      for (var i=1;i<e.children.length;i++) {
                        e.children(i).style.display="block";
                      }
                    }
                    else if (mark.innerText=="-") {
                      mark.innerText="+";
                      for (var i=1;i<e.children.length;i++) {
                        e.children(i).style.display="none";
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  function ch2(e) {
                    mark=e.children(0).children(0);
                    contents=e.children(1);
                    if (mark.innerText=="+") {
                      mark.innerText="-";
                      if (contents.className=="db"||contents.className=="cb") {
                        contents.style.display="block";
                      }
                      else {
                        contents.style.display="inline";
                      }
                    }
                    else if (mark.innerText=="-") {
                      mark.innerText="+";
                      contents.style.display="none";
                    }
                  }
                  function cl() {
                    e=window.event.srcElement;
                    if (e.className!="c") {
                      e=e.parentElement;
                      if (e.className!="c") {
                        return;
                      }
                    }
                    e=e.parentElement;
                    if (e.className=="e") {
                      ch(e);
                    }
                    if (e.className=="k") {
                      ch2(e);
                    }
                  }
                  function ex(){}
                  function h(){window.status=" ";}
                  document.onclick=cl;
              ]]>
          </xsl:comment>
        </SCRIPT>
        <STYLE>
          BODY {font:x-small 'Verdana'; margin-right:1.5em}
          .c  {cursor:hand}
          .b  {color:red; font-family:'Courier New'; font-weight:bold;
          text-decoration:none}
          .e  {margin-left:1em; text-indent:-1em; margin-right:1em}
          .k  {margin-left:1em; text-indent:-1em; margin-right:1em}
          .t  {color:#990000}
          .xt {color:#990099}
          .ns {color:red}
          .dt {color:green}
          .m  {color:blue}
          .tx {font-weight:bold}
          .db {text-indent:0px; margin-left:1em; margin-top:0px;
          margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:.3em;
          border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC; font:small Courier}
          .di {font:small Courier}
          .d  {color:blue}
          .pi {color:blue}
          .cb {text-indent:0px; margin-left:1em; margin-top:0px;
          margin-bottom:0px;padding-left:.3em; font:small Courier;
          color:#888888}
          .ci {font:small Courier; color:#888888}
          PRE {margin:0px; display:inline}
        </STYLE>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY class="st">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
    <DIV class="e">
      <SPAN class="b">
        <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
          <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>&lt;?</xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="pi">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>?></xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xml')">
    <DIV class="e">
      <SPAN class="b">
        <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
          <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>&lt;?</xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="pi">
        <xsl:text>xml </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>?></xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <SPAN>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:if test="xsl:*/@*">
          <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    </SPAN>
    <SPAN class="m">="</SPAN>
    <B>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </B>
    <SPAN class="m">"</SPAN>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <DIV class="e">
      <SPAN class="b"> </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="tx">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </SPAN>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <DIV class="k">
      <SPAN>
        <A STYLE="visibility:hidden" class="b" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()">-</A>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>&lt;!--</xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="ci" id="clean">
        <PRE>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </PRE>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="b">
        <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
          <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </SPAN>
      <SPAN class="m">
        <xsl:text>--></xsl:text>
      </SPAN>
      <SCRIPT>f(clean);</SCRIPT>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <DIV class="e">
      <DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em">
        <SPAN class="b">
          <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
            <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </SPAN>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>/></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[node()]">
    <DIV class="e">
      <DIV class="c">
        <A class="b" href="#" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()">-</A>
        <SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </SPAN>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </DIV>
      <DIV>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <DIV>
          <SPAN class="b">
            <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
              <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN class="m">
            <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
              <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
                <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN class="m">
            <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
          </SPAN>
        </DIV>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[text() and not (comment() or processing-instruction())]">
    <DIV class="e">
      <DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em">
        <SPAN class="b">
          <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
            <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </SPAN>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="tx">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="m">&lt;/</SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        </SPAN>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[*]" priority="20">
    <DIV class="e">
      <DIV STYLE="margin-left:1em;text-indent:-2em" class="c">
        <A class="b" href="#" onclick="return false" onfocus="h()">-</A>
        <SPAN class="m">&lt;</SPAN>
        <SPAN>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
              <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          <xsl:if test="@*">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </SPAN>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <SPAN class="m">
          <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
        </SPAN>
      </DIV>
      <DIV>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <DIV>
          <SPAN class="b">
            <xsl:call-template name="entity-ref">
              <xsl:with-param name="name">nbsp</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN class="m">
            <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
              <xsl:if test="xsl:*">
                <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:text>t</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          </SPAN>
          <SPAN class="m">
            <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
          </SPAN>
        </DIV>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="entity-ref">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Create a new window (or in my case, a usercontrol):

```
<UserControl x:Class="AdditionalXmlView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Framework">
    <WebBrowser ui:AttachedWebBrowserProperties.BindableXmlData="{Binding XmlData}" />
</UserControl>
```

Create a viewmodel like this:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Xsl
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class AdditionalXmlViewModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _XmlData As String
    Public Property XmlData() As String
        Get
            Return _XmlData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _XmlData = value
            OnPropertyChanged("XmlData")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub LoadXmlData(ByVal xmlDocument As XmlDocument)
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(2500)
        Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
        Dim stylesheetStream As Stream = GetType(AdditionalXmlView).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApplication.Framework.XmlToHtmlStylesheet.xslt")

        If stylesheetStream IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim xmlReader As XmlReader = xmlReader.Create(stylesheetStream)

            xslt.Load(xmlReader)
            Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
            Dim dest As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)
            xslt.Transform(xmlDocument, dest)
        End If

        XmlData = sb.ToString()
    End Sub


    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Create your view and viewmodel and set the xmldata:

```
Public Class XYZ
    Private additionalView As AdditionalXmlView
    Private additionalViewModel As AdditionalXmlViewModel

    Private Sub CreateInstances()
        additionalViewModel = New AdditionalXmlViewModel()
        additionalView = New AdditionalXmlView()
        additionalView.DataContext = additionalViewModel
    End Sub

   Private Sub SetXmlDataOfAdditionalView()
        Dim xmlDocument As New XmlDocument()
        xmlDocument.Load("myXmlFile.xml")

        additionalViewModel.LoadXmlData(xmlDocument)
   End Sub
End Class
```